# RxJava Single.just() vs Single.fromCallable()?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I wondered if someone can shed some light on this question, when to use

```
Single.fromCallable( ()-> myObject )
```

instead of

```
Single.just(myObject)
```

---

from the documentation, `Single.fromCallable()`:

```
 /**
 * Returns a {@link Single} that invokes passed function and emits its result for each new SingleObserver that subscribes.
 * <p>
 * Allows you to defer execution of passed function until SingleObserver subscribes to the {@link Single}.
 * It makes passed function "lazy".
 * Result of the function invocation will be emitted by the {@link Single}.
 * <dl>
 *   <dt><b>Scheduler:</b></dt>
 *   <dd>{@code fromCallable} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @param callable
 *         function which execution should be deferred, it will be invoked when SingleObserver will subscribe to the {@link Single}.
 * @param <T>
 *         the type of the item emitted by the {@link Single}.
 * @return a {@link Single} whose {@link SingleObserver}s' subscriptions trigger an invocation of the given function.
 */
```

and the documentation for `Single.just()`:

```
 /**
 * Returns a {@code Single} that emits a specified item.
 * <p>
 * <img width="640" height="310" src="https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/Single.just.png" alt="">
 * <p>
 * To convert any object into a {@code Single} that emits that object, pass that object into the
 * {@code just} method.
 * <dl>
 * <dt><b>Scheduler:</b></dt>
 * <dd>{@code just} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @param item
 *            the item to emit
 * @param <T>
 *            the type of that item
 * @return a {@code Single} that emits {@code item}
 * @see <a href="http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html">ReactiveX operators documentation: Just</a>
 */
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In the use case you've mentioned, there is actually no major difference.

Now imagine we need the object to be created dynamically through a function call?

```
fun getTimeObject() {
    val timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return TimeObject(timeInMillis)
}
```

Then with, `Single.just(getTimeObject())` the resulting `Single` will emit the same `Long` when it has a new subscriber.

However, with `Single.fromcallable(()-> getTimeObject())`, the resulting `Single` will emit a different `Long` indicating the current time in millis when it has a new subscriber.

That's because `fromCallable` executes it's lambda everytime it has a new subscriber **Lazily**.

Comment: I found this example excellent, because it shows significant difference between these 2 functions in very short lines. Should be written into a textbook!

Answer (score 67):

Usually you will notice the difference when the thing you're emitting is not just an object but actually a result of some method calls that involve either heavy computation, I/O, or state.

`Single.just(x)` evaluates the `x` immediately in the current thread and then you're left with whatever was the result of `x`, for all subscribers.

`Single.fromCallable(y)` invokes the `y` callable in the `subscribeOn` scheduler at the time of subscription and separately for each subscriber.

---

So for example, if you wanted to offload an I/O operation to a background thread, you'd use

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> someIoOperation()).
    subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
    subscribe(value -> updateUi(value), error -> handleError(error));
```

Having `Single.just()` here would not work since `someIoOperation()` would be executed on the current thread.

Answer (score 2):

You should use *fromCallable()* when you have a function like

```
MyObject myFunction() {
    // some login here
    return new MyObject();
}
```

Then you can create *Single* from this function like this:

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> myFunction());
```

*Single.just(myObject)* just emits your object without any logic.

So there is no need to use *fromCallable()* when you want to emit specific item.

Answer (score 2):

In the documents they distinguished between two times **Assemble time** and **Runtime**;

> **Assembly time**
>   The preparation of dataflows by applying various intermediate operators
>
> **Runtime**
>   This is the state when the flows are actively emitting items

Simply **Single.just()** is evaluated in the **Assembly time** not after the main process is completed

**Single.defer() and Single.fromcallable()**  evaluate the Single object in **Runtime**

Please check official documents code examples [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent)