# Observable.just(doSomeLongStuff()) run doSomeLongStuff() before I subscribe to observable

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have stupid problem with RxJava2.

I need to run two long operations at the same time. I know that I should use Observable.zip() and I use it.

The problem, that my long operations is run one after another and another problem that my long operations starting before I subscribe to them.

Let's imagine that this is my long operation that I should run async.

```
private String doSomethingLong() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt(5);
        Timber.i("Do something for [%d] sec [%s]", value, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(value * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Exception [%s]", e.getMessage());
        }
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"Job for [%d] seconds", value);
    }
```

And let there is a method like test() that will try to make it parallel:

```
public void test() {

        final long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Observable<String> just1 = Observable.just(doSomethingLong()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<String> just2 = Observable.just(doSomethingLong()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());


        Observable.zip(just1, just2, new Func2<String, String, Combined>() {
            @Override
            public Combined call(String s, String s2) {
                return new Combined(s, s2);
            }
        }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Combined>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Combined combined) {
                long total = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
                Timber.i("TOTAL [%d]ms [%s]", total, combined.toString());
            }
        });

    }
```

When I'm trying to run this I observe that two observables just1 and just2 runs one after another... And it's confused me...

But there is another staff that confused me more... I commented Observable.zip and noticed that just1 and just2 started method doSomethingLong() before I subscribed to them...

Let me show:

```
public void test() {

        final long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Observable<String> just1 = Observable.just(doSomethingLong()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        Observable<String> just2 = Observable.just(doSomethingLong()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());


//        Observable.zip(just1, just2, new Func2<String, String, Combined>() {
//            @Override
//            public Combined call(String s, String s2) {
//                return new Combined(s, s2);
//            }
//        }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Combined>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCompleted() {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onError(Throwable e) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onNext(Combined combined) {
//                long total = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
//                Timber.i("TOTAL [%d]ms [%s]", total, combined.toString());
//            }
//        });

    }
```

This code make almost same - it's run two times doSomethingLong() one after another...

What I'm expect:
 1. I need that doSomethingLong() methods run parallel
 2. I'm asking to explain why those methods runs before I start subscribe them.
 3. How should I write me code well in this situation. I want that doSomethingLong() methods do not called before I subscribe to them.

Thanks a lot. Hope that I explain problem well.

Comment: You need to `defer`. The method `doLongStuff` will be called to call `just`. You could also use `create` rather than `just`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava Single.just() vs Single.fromCallable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670628/rxjava-single-just-vs-single-fromcallable)

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding and indeed has been asked many times before. The underlying problem is that parenthesis doesn't magically defer execution of the method - not sure why people think that. 

You call `doSomethingLong()` to get a value, then create a source with that value at which point that value is a constant reference from RxJava's perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.just` doesn't run anything when you subscribe. It emits the elements when you subscribe, but your `doSomethingLong` will run as soon as you pass it as an argument. That's normal and it's how the language works.

What you're looking for is a way to say return this when we subscribe, but also only run it at that time and hopefully on a background thread.

There are a couple of answers for this, here are some:

**Using defer**

There's an operator called `defer` which takes a lambda which will be executed once you subscribe:

```
Observable.defer(() ->  doSomethingLong())
```

This will only execute `doSomethingLong` when you subscribe

**Using fromCallable**

You can create an observable from a lambda. This is known as `fromCallable`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> doSomethingLong())
```

Similarly, this will only run `doSomethingLong` when you subscribe

**Using create**

I think this is perhaps the most discouraged way of doing it, since there's a couple of things you have to deal with, but I think for the she of completeness it's ok to mention:

```
Observable.create( emitter -> {
    if(emitter.isDisposed()) return;

    emitter.onNext(doSomethingLong());
    emitter.onComplete();
});
```

Again, I'm sure there's more ways of doing this. I just wanted to explain the issue and give some options.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Observables as Observable.fromCallable{}.
And instead of zip use combineLatest()

Docs:
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html