# Generating UUID in WebFlux

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's say I have such a method in class implementing `BeforeConvertCall<Object>`

```
 @Override
    public Publisher<Object> onBeforeConvert(Object o, SqlIdentifier sqlIdentifier) {
        
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> enhance(o)); (A)
        //
        return Mono.just(o)
        .map(this::enhance); (B)

    }

private Object enhance(Object o) {

    if (o instanceof Foo && ((Foo) o).getId() == null) {
        ((Foo) o).setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    } 
    return o;
}
```

1. Is this code blocking? I mean should one be concerned?
2. Does it make sense to wrap `UUID` generation by `ThreadLocal` in reactor?
3. Is there any difference between (A) and (B) calls?

I tried also put inside a enhance method this time-consuming operation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
```

and made 3 concurrent requests.
4 `reactor-http-nio` threads were spawned all in the runnable state. First did lock `SecureRandom` and rest 3:

```
- locked <0x0000000600c4b510> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
- locked <0x0000000600c4b4b0> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
```

4. Why the rest 3 threads were not blocked because of the lock on the `SecureRandom` instance?

I tried to place the same for cycle into main pipeline within `doNext()` hook and there suddenly rest threads got blocked as expected.

5. Why did they get blocked here but with the same approach within the `onBeforeConvert()` they did not?
   Moreover, when I tried to wrap the call with the `ThreadLocal`, it did not help.

> java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)   at
> sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(java.base@11.0.10/SecureRandom.java:216)
>
> - waiting to lock <0x0000000600118b28> (a sun.security.provider.SecureRandom)

6. I would expect to all 4 threads have own instance of `SecureRandom`.. or not?
   Is it perhaps so that only main thread own the instance and it populates work to the working threads which have no thread-local of `SecureRandom`?

Last one experiment:

```
 @Override
    public Publisher<Object> onBeforeConvert(Object o, SqlIdentifier sqlIdentifier) {
        
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> enhance(o))
        .map(this::enhance)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()); (C)

    }
```

After adding line (C) and running 4 concurrent requests, `boundedElastic-2`,3,4 did get blocked.

7. Why did they get blocked though `reactor-http-nio` in the previous approach did not get blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, in the way you show this code snippet - here, the UUID generation is blocking.
2. No
3. Till `subscribeOn` is not called, there is no significant difference between those two. The `just` is evaluated imediately for all the subscribers, when the `fromCallable` is evaluated at the time of subscription and separately for each subscriber.
   See more here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670628/rxjava-single-just-vs-single-fromcallable)

The best idea is to use:

```
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> enhance(o))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

With this approach you delegate blocking logic to the separate thread pool `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` so the main reactor thread pool is not blocked and you make not impact on whole application